# How to manually create anchor links in jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a jupyter notebook with a huge amount of cells in it.  Navigating becomes a problem.

Is there a way to create anchor links manually within the markup?

Please note, I am not looking to create external anchor links or install a table of contents type of plugin, but am just asking how to set a few internal anchor links to one notebook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you can use html in Jupyter Notebooks there are many ways to set anchor links.
I usually use this in the first line of the cell I want to link to `<a class="anchor" name="myCell"></a>`.
To link to it use `[text with link](#myCell)`.